# REST API router forward to Apollo GraphQL endpoinr

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

I have a node/express/Apollo application to provide GraphQL service to the frontend application. I also have the REST API endpoing in the application to provide service for legacy applications. I want to forward the REST API calls to the GraphQL endpoint. For example:

From

```
GET /api/roles
```

to

```
POST /graphql

   { *body* }
```

I tried like this:

// app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import routes from './routes';

const port = process.env.PORT || 8088;
const app = express();

app.use('/api/roles', routes.role);

const server = new ApolloServer({
     ......  
  },
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });

app.listen({ port: port }, () => {
  console.log(`Apollo Server on http://localhost:${port}/graphql`);
});
```

// routes/role.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = '/graphql';
  req.originalUrl = '/graphql';
  req.method = 'POST';
  req.body = `
      {
          findRoles {
              data {
                  roleId
                  name
              }
          }
      }`;

  return router.handle(req, res, next);
});
```

It doesn't work and gives the error "Cannot POST /graphql". Any idea how to do it?